# htaccess for Silex from the root folder not working as intended

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, silex

I tried to search and use the solutions already posted but nothing worked for now and I tried pretty much everything I could but didn't work.

These are the app directories:

```
localhost/
  root/
    data/
    app/
    public/
      index.php
    .htaccess
```

The htaccess is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /root/public/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The first problem is that if I go to localhost/root/public the website works as intended but in the url I still see 'public' which I'd like to remove.

The second problem is that my objective is to go to the index from the url localhost/root/ but now, if I go there it just shows the files in the folder.

Thank you.

As requested, these are the routes that I use:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    // code
})->bind('home');

$app->get('/about-me', function () use ($app) {
    // code
})->bind('about-me');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your system.

First:
The .htaccess located in the root folder should be used to remove the 'public' part of the URL. The code for that is like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

It basically grabs every route and redirects it to the public folder, exactly as you wished!

Second:
You should create another .htaccess file in your '/public' folder to redirect everything to the index.php file. The code for that should look like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

You should end up with the following structure:

```
localhost/
  root/
    .htaccess (removes 'public')
    data/
    app/
    public/
      index.php
      .htaccess (forward to index.php)
```

This should solve both your problems. If it does, please mark the question as completed by marking my answer as the one that solved it. If it does not, please comment on other problems that occur to you!

Comment: Now it does redirect to the public folder, but when I'm in the index.php I still see the url as 'localhost/root/public/', is there something that can remove the 'public' folder to show in the url?

Comment: What happens when you try to load 'localhost/root/'? If you are then redirected to the public folder, something might be wrong with your route mouting. But first test what happens on 'localhost/root/'. If there is still a problem, I'll help you out!

Comment: Yes, I get redirected from 'localhost/root/' to 'localhost/root/public/'

Comment: Hmm, then the mounting might me a problem. Could you please add one of your routes to your original question. (the $app->get(...) or $app->post(...) parts)

Comment: There should be some mistake in your code. But I just can't think what it might be. I could check your code if you want? Either send me an Github link with the project or you could send it to my email: lexdewilligen@gmail.com. (I only need your root file with what's in it, not the silex part (which I think is located in your app folder))

Comment: I tried another test, I changed my index.php with a simple echo and your rewrite rules and the problem is still the same. I'm starting to wonder if it's my apache that is somehow behaving weird.

Comment: Yes, the redirecting is very weird. Since I'm sure these codes are fine..